# Client computer blocked by postfix

Tags: linux, networking, email, postfix, suse

I have been trying to connect from a Windows client computer to a Postfix server running on a Suse Linux Enterprise 2012 SP3 but it has been completely impossible.

Connection is not possible either with an email client or via telnet, but ping is ok and ssh also.

Checking the postfix configuration, I specifically enabled the mynetworks setting to allow the client ip address (but it's in the same ip range that the server so there shouldn't be any problem).

The thing is that the server works ok... But just from localhost. I have checked firewall policies and nothing seems "wrong".

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you need any more data please tell me. :-)

Thanks!

Comment: When you try to telnet, what is the response you get?

Comment: Network error: connection refused. I'm trying to run nmap to see if port 25 is answering but I'm having some problems with it but all the tests I have made it seems like the service is ok.

Comment: Problem solved, after seeing with nmap that port 25 was not open; it was because in the inet_interfaces=localhost, so only localhost was able to see the smtp server. Now it's localhost and the client computer.